# How can I improve the query with grouping?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]
How can I add a grouping for the "`retirements`" table by the "`id_type`" field and not just for everyone?

```
select name,
  sum(retirements.price_per_product) 
from retirements 
join type_of_products top on retirements.id_product = top.id
where (date between '1998-11-01' and '1998-11-14')
group by name;
```

*Do not resort to aggregate functions of each type?* It's so rude.

Comment: 'Do not resort to aggregate functions of each type? It's so rude' - I am baffled by this statement.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you're asking but why not just change your `group by` to `group by name, retirements.id_type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways to achieve this.

```
1. You may use a sub-query but it is expensive in terms of performance.
2. You may utilize the #temp table and join it in later part. A downside is it is
```

longer to code but performance is good especially in the long run.

Comment: I'm a fool, help me write a query

Comment: Please try this: select name, id_type,
  sum(retirements.price_per_product) 
from retirements 
join type_of_products top on retirements.id_product = top.id
where (date between '1998-11-01' and '1998-11-14')
group by name,id_type;